# What does IIS time mean?

Tags: iis, iis-6

Simple one but a question that Google is failing to help with. In IIS logging, the field `time`. Is this the time IIS received the request or the time it responded?

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2013-03-04 08:32:02
#Fields: date **time** s-sitename s-computername
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IIS Advanced Logging uses the W3C log file format to log information about all sites on the server
>
> **Time-Local**
>
> Logs the time at which the request occurred, in local time.
>
> **Time-UTC**
>
> Logs the time at which the request occurred, in UTC.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791933(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: But define **occurred**? It's a long running process, the time taken is 2 minutes. So is this when it received the request or responded?

Comment: "The request occurred" is when the request was received.  You can easily test this by creating a page that creates an artificial 2 minute delay and checking the logging.

Comment: The "time the request occurred" is implicitly the time the request arrived, the "time taken" field is the time it took (milliseconds) to process and send the reply. Note that requests are only logged *after* completion, since the HTTP code is logged, and that's not known until processing is complete.

Comment: Note that the request may arrive and be queued before processing begins, if the system load is high.  The logged time should be the time the request first touches IIS, potentially (again, under load) before request *processing* begins.

Comment: I believe there are 3 variables, 1) when the request hits the request queue (`Time-Local` `Time-UTC`), 2) when the request starts to be serviced (`Begin Request-UTC`), and 3) the time spent serving the response (`Time Taken`).

Comment: @JayWalker maybe in IIS 7 but not IIS 6.0.